# paperclip - path in image.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip for uploading images in my rails application.

I have 2 models 'Image' and 'Book' where one book can have many Images and image belongs_to Book.
In my 'images' table, I have 4 columns:

- id
- book_id
- data_file_path
- data_file_name

column 'data_file_path' stores the path of the image and column 'data_file_name' stores the image name and extension

In my image.rb file, I have the following lines of code:

```
has_attached_file :data, :path => "http://www.test.org/book/book_images/:data_file_path/:book_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                         :url =>    "http://www.test.org/book/book_images/:data_file_path/:book_id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Notice the ':data_file_path' in the code above.

In my view, when i do <%=image.data.url(:thumb)%> i get the following path:

```
http://www.test.org/book/book_images/data_file_path/9124/thumb/1897_EK91_201107.jpg
```

Instead of retrieving the data_file_path value from the d-base, it's displaying the variable name.

How to I get the data_file_path value in the url.

Thanks a lot for your precious help. I have struggling with that since a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I finally figured it out. I needed to use Paperclip.interpolates.

I added the following in config/initializers/paperclip.rb file

```
  Paperclip.interpolates :data_file_path do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.data_file_path 
  end
```

Then just add 'data_file_path' to the path in image.rb:

```
has_attached_file :data, :path => "http://www.test.org/book/book_images/:data_file_path/:book_id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                         :url =>    "http://www.test.org/book/book_images/:data_file_path/:book_id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Hope this might be of help to somebody else :)
cheers